# Getting error after changing table of data source on AWS Appsync from Amplify project

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have one issue about Appsync. After writting schema from my amplify project, I go to Appsync page and change the datasource to my existing table from DynamoDB. Everying is alright, but when I try to query, I get this error:

[image]

So what shoud I do now to avoid this error ?